# o.n.b.v.t.BoltProtocolV1- Failed to write response to driver Cannot write to buffer when closed

Tags: neo4j, neo4j-python-driver

I am using **neo4j 3.1.3** version where I am getting following error:

```
2018-02-28 05:17:27.780+0000 ERROR [o.n.b.v.t.BoltProtocolV1] Failed to write response to driver Cannot write to buffer when closed
java.io.IOException: Cannot write to buffer when closed
    at org.neo4j.bolt.v1.transport.ChunkedOutput.ensure(ChunkedOutput.java:163)
    at org.neo4j.bolt.v1.transport.ChunkedOutput.writeShort(ChunkedOutput.java:94)
    at org.neo4j.bolt.v1.packstream.PackStream$Packer.packStructHeader(PackStream.java:330)
    at org.neo4j.bolt.v1.messaging.BoltResponseMessageWriter.onSuccess(BoltResponseMessageWriter.java:72)
    at org.neo4j.bolt.v1.messaging.MessageProcessingHandler.onFinish(MessageProcessingHandler.java:111)
    at org.neo4j.bolt.v1.runtime.BoltStateMachine.after(BoltStateMachine.java:105)
    at org.neo4j.bolt.v1.runtime.BoltStateMachine.run(BoltStateMachine.java:201)
    at org.neo4j.bolt.v1.messaging.BoltMessageRouter.lambda$onRun$3(BoltMessageRouter.java:80)
    at org.neo4j.bolt.v1.runtime.concurrent.RunnableBoltWorker.execute(RunnableBoltWorker.java:135)
    at org.neo4j.bolt.v1.runtime.concurrent.RunnableBoltWorker.run(RunnableBoltWorker.java:89)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

I have used following configurations:

```
dbms.memory.heap.initial_size=8g
dbms.memory.heap.max_size=8g
dbms.memory.pagecache.size=4g

Machine description: 4 vCPUs, 15 GB memory
```

My neo4j client is Python so using **neo4j python driver, version 1.5.3**. I am getting following error on client side:

```
[2018-02-28 10:59:43,838: ERROR/MainProcess] Task api_keyword.tasks.job.update_application_rel[14f5baa6-09a5-44df-9bd7-982116e0b184] raised unexpected: ServiceUnavailable("Failed to write to closed connection Address(host='10.160.0.9', port=7687)",)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ubuntu/celeryprod/lib/python3.5/site-packages/celery/app/trace.py", line 240, in trace_task
    R = retval = fun(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/ubuntu/celeryprod/lib/python3.5/site-packages/celery/app/trace.py", line 438, in __protected_call__
    return self.run(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/ubuntu/celeryprod/api/src/api_keyword/tasks/job.py", line 21, in update_application_rel
    rel_label='APPLIED'
  File "/home/ubuntu/celeryprod/api/src/api_keyword/utils/neo4j/base.py", line 76, in delete_relationship
    self.run_query(neo4j_query)
  File "/home/ubuntu/celeryprod/api/src/api_keyword/utils/neo4j/base.py", line 32, in run_query
    res = Neo4jConnector().run_query(neo4j_query)
  File "/home/ubuntu/celeryprod/lib/python3.5/site-packages/retrying.py", line 49, in wrapped_f
    return Retrying(*dargs, **dkw).call(f, *args, **kw)
  File "/home/ubuntu/celeryprod/lib/python3.5/site-packages/retrying.py", line 212, in call
    raise attempt.get()
  File "/home/ubuntu/celeryprod/lib/python3.5/site-packages/retrying.py", line 247, in get
    six.reraise(self.value[0], self.value[1], self.value[2])
  File "/home/ubuntu/celeryprod/lib/python3.5/site-packages/six.py", line 686, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/home/ubuntu/celeryprod/lib/python3.5/site-packages/retrying.py", line 200, in call
    attempt = Attempt(fn(*args, **kwargs), attempt_number, False)
  File "/home/ubuntu/celeryprod/lib/python3.5/site-packages/timeout_decorator/timeout_decorator.py", line 81, in new_function
    return function(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/ubuntu/celeryprod/api/src/core/services/neo4j.py", line 56, in run_query
    result = session.run(cypher_query)
  File "/home/ubuntu/celeryprod/lib/python3.5/site-packages/neo4j/v1/api.py", line 339, in run
    self._connection.send()
  File "/home/ubuntu/celeryprod/lib/python3.5/site-packages/neo4j/bolt/connection.py", line 263, in send
    self._send()
  File "/home/ubuntu/celeryprod/lib/python3.5/site-packages/neo4j/bolt/connection.py", line 275, in _send
    raise self.Error("Failed to write to closed connection {!r}".format(self.server.address))
neo4j.exceptions.ServiceUnavailable: Failed to write to closed connection Address(host='10.160.0.9', port=7687)
```

I am initializing driver like this:

```
 self.driver = GraphDatabase.driver("bolt://{0}".format(self.neo4j_db_url),
                                              auth=basic_auth(self.neo4j_username, self.neo4j_password), connection_timeout=60)
```

Can anyone help me regarding this. Any configuration I need to tune, or any other configuration I need to define?

Comment: Did you check whether your db accepts remote connections?

Comment: Yes it is accepting remote connections. Set this in conf: dbms.connectors.default_listen_address

Comment: then did you try using a local IP rather than global one which is mentioned?

Comment: `driver = GraphDatabase.driver("bolt://localhost:7687", auth=basic_auth("neo4j", "neo"))
session = driver.session()` - try this can you.

Comment: My python client is on different machine than graph. So localhost won't work.

Comment: It was just for syntax.. copy your IP there but not use it as it is. :)

Comment: I am doing the same thing. I don't see what is different in your syntax.

Comment: This is the IP(10.160.0.9-global) you are using try the local one like 192.168.xx.xx.